# Linq c# - Join Multiple Conditions Error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a query with a 3 conditions on a join. But I get an error. In the `sql server` it's working perfectly, but when I try to convert it to `linq` it's giving me an erro.

You can take a look below the error and the query.

Query:

```
var temp = _context
                   .FavouriteVol
                   .Join(_context.Favourites,
                            fv => new { fv.EntityId, fv.CountryId, fv.EType },
                            f => new { f.EntityId, f.CountryId, f.EType },
                                (fv, f) => new { Favourites = f, FavouriteVol = fv })
                                .Where(u => u.Favourites.userId == userId)
                                .Select(f => f.Favourites)
                                .ToList();
```

Note: `EntityId` (int), `CountryId` (string), and `EType` (int)`.
The problem is with the string. but I need filter also with the string, so any idea how can I do it.

Error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Join(System.Linq.IQueryable, 
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, 
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' 
>   cannot be inferred from the usage.

Sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM db.FavouriteVol FV
INNER JOIN db.Favourite F On F.EType = FV.EType and F.CountryId = FV.CountryId and F.EType = FV.EType
WHERE F.userId = 5
```

Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: What are the exact types of the `EntityId`, `CountryId`, and `EType` properties?

Comment: @GertArnold ``EntityId`` (int), ``CountryId`` (string), and ``EType`` (int) any idea how to fix it? I can not change the types on the database.

Comment: @GertArnold Well the problem is with the string. Do you know any solution for this? :)

Comment: Well I suppose it because if I remove the string, it's working ok. ``(=> new { fv.EntityId, fv.EType }, f => new { f.EntityId, f.EType },)`` I don't know why :s

Comment: show your sql code please

Comment: 1. Are the CountryID columns string in both tables? 2. You really want a list of booleans out?

Comment: Both country columns are ``string``(eg. 'IRL') on the database. I know it's a little bit confuse but I didn't create this app. I just trying to fix a problem on it and I need it. I have no idea why doesn't work the condition with the ``string`` . Any suggestion or something to try to get it working?

Comment: Just to pin it down, what happens if you join by `fv.EntityId, fv.EType` and add `.Where(u => u.Favourites.CountryId == u.FavouriteVol.CountryId)`?

Comment: @GertArnold It's the only solution I can see. I'll try and I let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: @GertArnold your solution it's working perfectly.. so would you like write an answer to get the points? Also what I would like know is why I cant implement the query like I was trying before with the ``country`` on the join not in the where

Comment: Well, that's what I'd like to know too. So this was not really meant as an answer (although I don't mind adding it), but as a means to nail the problem. Is this SQL Server by the way?

Comment: @GertArnold yep it's sql server.Also we have an app to read the queries are executing in the server, so we can see what it's executing and the query it's generate is the one I want. I mean the country it's in the join not in the where. So in the background it's executing the proper query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not clear to me why the join including `CountryId` causes this error, you can work around the problem by matching the `CountryId`s separately:

```
var temp = _context
           .FavouriteVol
           .Join(_context.Favourites,
                    fv => new { fv.EntityId, fv.EType },
                    f => new { f.EntityId, f.EType },
                        (fv, f) => new { Favourites = f, FavouriteVol = fv })
                        .Where(u => u.Favourites.userId == userId
                                 && u.Favourites.CountryId == u.FavouriteVol.CountryId)
                        .Select(f => f.Favourites)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Let me know if you find why we can not set the ``country`` (string) on the ``join`` and do it on the ``where``. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your selector in your Join clause is the problem.

```
.Join(_context.Favourites,
       fv => new { fv.EntityId, fv.CountryId, fv.EType },
       f => new { f.EntityId, f.CountryId, f.EType },
       (fv, f) => new { Favourites = f, FavouriteVol = fv }
)
```

In LinqToObjects, that expression will work fine but it is invalid in LinqToEntities.

**You have two options.**

You can either Mark the return sets as Enumerable, in which case all Entities from the sets will be returned to the client and filtered there (not good for performance).
You will get back an anonymously typed object that contains two properties (the entities you're interested in).

*Note: I have reworked the queries somewhat. I noticed you are testing for whether Favourites == null.  That is already taken care of for you with a Join which maps to SQL's INNER JOIN.*

```
var temp = _context
             .FavouriteVol
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Join(
                _context.Favourites
                      .Where(u => u.userId == userId)
                      .AsEnumerable(),
                fv => new { fv.EntityId, fv.CountryId, fv.EType },
                f => new { f.EntityId, f.CountryId, f.EType },
                (fv, f) => new { FavouriteVol = fv, Favourites = f }
             )
             .ToList();
```

Or you will have to specify all returned fields explicitly.  For this approach, you will need to either name the properties carefully or just create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) to hold the return values you are interested in.

```
var temp = _context
             .FavouriteVol
             .Join(
                _context.Favourites
                      .Where(u => u.userId == userId),
                fv => new { fv.EntityId, fv.CountryId, fv.EType },
                f => new { f.EntityId, f.CountryId, f.EType },
                (fv, f) => new { 
                   EntityId = fv.EntityId, 
                   CountryId = fv.CountryId, 
                   EType = fv.EType, 
                   //<other fv properties>, 
                   UserId = f.UserId, 
                   //<other f properties>  
                }
             )
             .ToList();
```

Comment: "It seems your selector in your Join clause is the problem". Then why does a join without the `CountryId` work without any problems?

Comment: To be honest, I generally do not use anonymous types in my joins or projections.  I tend to define my DTO's ahead of time because I have been burnt by similarly named anonymous type fields in different locations in the same assembly that have different underlying types.  I also do a lot of joins that involve fields of different types int, string and DateTime all mixed in.  Perhaps if you give me the schemas for FavouriteVol and Favourites, I can create a sample and justify my approach.